# Bootstrap datetimepicker - How to set all picker tooltips at once?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-datetimepicker

The following are my example codes:

```
$('#ex1').datetimepicker({
    tooltips: {
            today: 'today',
            clear: 'clear',
            close: 'close',
        },
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        locale: 'zh-tw',
});

$('#ex2').datetimepicker({
    tooltips: {
            today: 'today',
            clear: 'clear',
            close: 'close',
        },
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        locale: 'zh-tw',
});

$('#ex3').datetimepicker({
    tooltips: {
            today: 'today',
            clear: 'clear',
            close: 'close',
        },
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        locale: 'zh-tw',
});
```

As above, the code is duplicate!
How to set all picker tooltips and option at once?

I have tried add them to "calendar" class, and use

```
$('.calendar').datetimepicker({
    tooltips: {
            today: 'today',
            clear: 'clear',
            close: 'close',
        },
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        locale: 'zh-tw',
});
```

to set them, but not working...

Thank you!

---Updated: ---
These are my code about class:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control calendar"  id='leave-end'>
<input type='text' class="form-control calendar" id='leave-start'>
```

And:

```
$('.calendar').datetimepicker({
            tooltips: {
                close: '關閉日曆',
                selectMonth: '選擇月份',
                prevMonth: '上個月',
                nextMonth: '下個月',
                selectYear: '選擇年份',
                prevYear: '前一年',
                nextYear: '下一年',
            },
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            locale: 'zh-tw',
        });
```

But not working and no error message, what wrong?

And

```
var options = {
            tooltips: {
                today: 'today',
                clear: 'clear',
                close: 'close',
            },
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            locale: 'zh-tw',
        }
$('#leave-start').datetimepicker({options});
```

I copy and paste but got 1 warning 
`jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` 
and 1 error `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: Are you sure that u already add the classname to your html tag?

Comment: I add my code about classname to my html tag. Thank your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use variables.

```
var options = {
    tooltips: {
        today: 'today',
        clear: 'clear',
        close: 'close',
    },
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
    locale: 'zh-tw',
}

$('#ex1').datetimepicker({options});
$('#ex2').datetimepicker({options});
$('#ex3').datetimepicker({options});
```

Update: Adding `datetimepicker` by selecting class should also work so check if you set class correctly.

Comment: I copy and paste but got 
1 warning
`jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`
and 1 error
`jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: I add my code about classname to my html tag. Thank your answer!

Comment: what datetimepicker are you using?

Comment: First of all you want to instantinate `datetimepicker` too many times. You are doing it by binding to ids (`#leave-start`, `#leave-end`) and then by class. Choose one method. Second, replace `{options}` with `options` in `$('#leave-start').datetimepicker({options});`

Comment: OK! I got it! And it can work!
But I have another question:
I have many picker such as #1 #2 #3, 
They all have duplicate option as above, 
BUT, #3 should add additional option `format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'` 
How do I do?
Thank you very much!

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: you can extend `options` variable by: `var options2 = options;
  options2.format = 'YYYY/MM/DD';`

Comment: It seems I don't have enough reputation to close question... : (

Comment: You accepted answer and that is clue for other people that problem was solved. It is enough.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!